# characteristic function - fourier pricing

Tags: options

Some literature states that, for instance for the Heston model, the characteristic function is given by:
$$\varphi_{\mathrm{H}}(u, t, T)=\exp \left(A(u, t, T)+B(u, t, T) V(t)+i u X(t)\right)$$

Other literature states that the characteristic function is given by
$$\varphi_{\mathrm{H}}(u, t, T)=\exp \left(A(u, t, T)+B(u, t, T) V(t)\right)$$,

without the $i u X(t)$ part. Why is someone including the last term, and other do not? I will price over-the-counter options using Lewis Fundamental Transform. Which of these should I use?

Comment: This is just an idea: if prices are normalized, x(t) is equal to zero.

Comment: I don't think thats the reason, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you please share the references where you found those formulae? The correct char fun for Heston is, for example, derived in Gatheral (2006).

Comment: If you're talking about the conditional characteristic function of the price of the underlying, you would expect at least two variables showing up. If you look in Heston (1993), you will find that the first one is correct. However, you do find the second one, you'd expect a term like $\exp(iu X(t))$ at the numerator of your integrand to appear nonetheless when you compute the probabiltiies in the BSM-like formula.

Comment: @Stéphane OP needs to be careful though with the Heston paper. There’s this “Heston trap” where you can get discontinuities if you use the original formula. So you need to change the sign of the square root, see Albrecher et al. (2007)